# What is the difference between the model.wv.vectors and model.syn1neg in Gensim's Word2Vec?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gensim, word2vec

I have just trained a Word2Vec model as follows:

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

model = Word2Vec(sentences=common_texts, vector_size=5, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)
```

Now, I want to find the actual embedding; the (*vocabulary_size x vector_size*) array. Looking at `dir(model)`, I see both `syn1neg` and `wv.vectors` as Numpy arrays with the dimensionality I am looking for. What information is stored in these arrays?